# Simplify partial binomial sum

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

We know that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n.$$
Is there a way (without a calculator) to simplify
$$\sum_{k=0}^{(\text{a number less than }n)} {n \choose k}?$$

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say is you can rewrite

$\sum_{j=0}^k {n\choose j} = \sum_{j=0}^k{n-k-1+j\choose j}2^{k-j}.$